# Find single class that implements particular interface but exclude extended interface sub - implementations with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I need to find classes that implements only one particular interfaces in my spring boot app. 
The problem i am facing is that the ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner is returning classes that implements the "extended" sub-interfaces as well.

Example:

```
public interface A {}

public interface B  extends A {}
public interface C  extends A {}
public interface D  extends A {}

public interface E  extends B {}
public interface F  extends B {}
public interface G  extends B {}
public interface H  extends B {}
public interface I  extends B {}
public interface J  extends B {}
```

here is the code that i am using so far:

```
        BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner s = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr);

        TypeFilter tf_include_1 = new AssignableTypeFilter(E.class);

        TypeFilter tf_exculude1 = new AssignableTypeFilter(C.class);
        TypeFilter tf_exculude2 = new AssignableTypeFilter(D.class);

        s.addIncludeFilter(tf_include_1);

        s.addExcludeFilter(tf_exculude1);
        s.addExcludeFilter(tf_exculude2);

        s.setIncludeAnnotationConfig(false);

//      s.resetFilters(false);
        s.scan("edu.university.ServiceLayer.*");  


        System.out.println("Printing all classes that implement the E");
        String[] beans = bdr.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String string : beans) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

Now the result is that the the array string "beans" contains all other classes such as F,G,H,I,J etc.

How can construct my TypeFitler in a way that in returns only the selected Class that implements only the specified interface i.e. to filter out all implementation that apply the extended interfaces. such as B except the class E.

Here is the code that works for me after changing the default constructor of ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner to ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr, false) as the user @Holger  suggested.

```
        BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr = new SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry();
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner s = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr, false);

        TypeFilter tf_include_1 = new AssignableTypeFilter(E.class);


        s.resetFilters(false);    

        s.addIncludeFilter(tf_include_1);

        s.setIncludeAnnotationConfig(false);

        s.scan("edu.university.ServiceLayer.*");  


        System.out.println("Printing all classes that implement the E");
        String[] beans = bdr.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String string : beans) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

please note that resetFilters has been commented out and its the order has been also changed

Comment: Why do you need this? From an OO perspective they all implement the interface, if you don't want that then don't let the other interfaces extend the interface in the first place...

Comment: create an empty `interface OnlyA extends A {}` and implement it in interested bean, then scan for `OnlyA` instead of `A`.

Comment: @M. Deinum  well i have used the strategy  pattern  together with the template pattenr in order to implement the service model in my app. That saved me a lot of typing but now i need to find a particular interface since they all extend each other. Basically that is the answer to your question why i need this. I was hoping that i can construct the TypeFilter in a particular way that will get me only that one interface.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou Well if i create such a single interface for each of my classes one more time that defeats the poinf of using the strategy and template patterns in my code. I need to somehow target that interface E.

Comment: I was thinking since it is possible to exclude the base interfcaes "C" and "D" and that is returning only interfaces that were extending B then it should be somehow possible to do it. i.e. return only E, since exclusion works , the TypeFilter needs to be constructed most likely in some particular way.

Comment: I don’t get it. There is no relationship between `E` and `B` or `C`. Nor is there one for `E` and the other ones from `E` to `J`. If you mandate that the types to find have to be assignable to `E`, why should the result contain any of the other interfaces?

Comment: @Holger well there is i.e. E extends B. Then B extends A, and the C extends A as well. Remember those are interfaces i.e. not classes.

Comment: So what? `B extends A` and `C extends A` but none of them is assignable to `E`. Only `E` or subtypes of  `E` are assignable to `E`. In your question, there is no subtype of `E`.

Comment: @Holger well the problem is not A or B or C the problem is that F,G,H,I,J are assignable to B and i need to filter them out. i.e. i need only interface E at the end, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Also none of F,G,H,I,J is assignable to `E`. Again, only `E` or subtypes of `E` are assignable to `E` and in your question, there is no subtype of `E`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107739/discussion-between-tito-and-holger).

Comment: Maybe it helps not to use the default filters, i.e. use the constructor `new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr, false)`. After all, a type only needs to match one of the inclusion filters to get accepted. [The default is to use default filters](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java#82)

Comment: @Holger that indeed works, I do not what those default filters are but when i did change the constructor of the ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner to (bdr, false) i know get only the interface E. Got bless you dude. Many thanks. If you what put that as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the types `C`, `D`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J` is assignable to `E` as they are not subtypes of `E` so a simple inclusion filter `new AssignableTypeFilter(E.class)` should do the job.

Your problem stems from the use of the `new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr)` constructor which will initialize the scanner with default filters as you can see [in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java#82). While a type will be checked against all exclusion filters, a single matching inclusion filter is enough for it to appear in the result. So you surely don’t want any other, potentially contradicting, inclusion filter.

So the solution is to use the constructor `new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(bdr, false)` instead.